# Help to choose lens

Tags: lens, canon, focal-length, fashion

I recent got 60d and EF-S 18-55mm Lens and i want to buy 1 more lens specially for product and fashion(portrait) photography...

I decided `EF50mm f/1.4 USM` and `EF85mm f/1.8 USM`? Which one would be best for my requirement or would i need both of them? Please suggest. I will even need another lens for macro shoots later.  thanks

Comment: See also  http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17316/15871

Comment: Please learn to use the search feature, every question you have asked has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

85mm is a great focal length for portraits. What you need to consider is that you're on a cropped sensor (1.6x). This means that a 50mm 1.4 will give you the equivelant of 80mm, close to the 85mm sweet spot. With this in mind, I'd recommend the 50mm 1.4 initially. If later you want to expand your collection, the 85mm(136mm equivelant) would be a good addition to outdoor portrait photography.